# How to query on fields from nested records without referring to the parent records in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have data structured as follows:

```
{ 
  "results": {
    "A": {"first": 1, "second": 2, "third": 3},
    "B": {"first": 4, "second": 5, "third": 6},
    "C": {"first": 7, "second": 8, "third": 9},
    "D": {"first": 1, "second": 2, "third": 3}, 
   ... },
  ...
}
```

i.e. nested records, where the lowest level has the same schema for all records in the level above. The schema would be similar to this:

```
results              RECORD    NULLABLE
results.A            RECORD    NULLABLE
results.A.first      INTEGER   NULLABLE
results.A.second     INTEGER   NULLABLE
results.A.third      INTEGER   NULLABLE
results.B            RECORD    NULLABLE
results.B.first      INTEGER   NULLABLE
...
```

Is there a way to do (e.g. aggregate) queries in BigQuery on fields from the lowest level, without knowledge of the keys on the (direct) parent level? Put differently, can I do a query on `first` for all records in `results` without having to specify `A`, `B`, ... in my query?

I would for example want to achieve something like

```
SELECT SUM(results.*.first) FROM table
```

in order to get `1+4+7+1 = 13`,
but `SELECT results.*.first` isn't supported.

(I've tried playing around with STRUCTs, but haven't gotten far.)

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: schema of table is still not clear! is it string field with json in it? or repeated record? please provide schema. the best way also to provide WITH statement to reproduce your data so we can help effectively

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to do (e.g. aggregate) queries in BigQuery on fields from the lowest level, without knowledge of the keys on the (direct) parent level?

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL and totally avoids referencing parent records (A, B, C, D, etc.)

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION Nested_SUM(entries ANY TYPE, field_name STRING) AS ((
  SELECT SUM(CAST(SPLIT(kv, ':')[OFFSET(1)] AS INT64))
  FROM UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(TO_JSON_STRING(entries), r'":{(.*?)}')) entry,
  UNNEST(SPLIT(entry)) kv
  WHERE TRIM(SPLIT(kv, ':')[OFFSET(0)], '"') = field_name
));
SELECT id, 
  Nested_SUM(results, 'first') AS first_sum,
  Nested_SUM(results, 'second') AS second_sum,
  Nested_SUM(results, 'third') AS third_sum,
  Nested_SUM(results, 'forth') AS forth_sum
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

if to apply to sample data from your question as in below example

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION Nested_SUM(entries ANY TYPE, field_name STRING) AS ((
  SELECT SUM(CAST(SPLIT(kv, ':')[OFFSET(1)] AS INT64))
  FROM UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(TO_JSON_STRING(entries), r'":{(.*?)}')) entry,
  UNNEST(SPLIT(entry)) kv
  WHERE TRIM(SPLIT(kv, ':')[OFFSET(0)], '"') = field_name
));
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 AS id, STRUCT(
    STRUCT(1 AS first, 2 AS second, 3 AS third) AS A,
    STRUCT(4 AS first, 5 AS second, 6 AS third) AS B,
    STRUCT(7 AS first, 8 AS second, 9 AS third) AS C,
    STRUCT(1 AS first, 2 AS second, 3 AS third) AS D
  ) AS results
)
SELECT id, 
  Nested_SUM(results, 'first') AS first_sum,
  Nested_SUM(results, 'second') AS second_sum,
  Nested_SUM(results, 'third') AS third_sum,
  Nested_SUM(results, 'forth') AS forth_sum
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

output is

```
Row id  first_sum   second_sum  third_sum   forth_sum    
1   1   13          17          21          null
```

Answer (score 3):

Below trick is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT id, ( 
    SELECT AS STRUCT 
      SUM(first) AS sum_first, 
      SUM(second) AS sum_second, 
      SUM(third) AS sum_third 
    FROM UNNEST([a]||[b]||[c]||[d])
  ).*
FROM `project.dataset.table`,
UNNEST([results])
```

You can test, play with above using dummy/sample data from your question as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 AS id, STRUCT(
    STRUCT(1 AS first, 2 AS second, 3 AS third) AS A,
    STRUCT(4 AS first, 5 AS second, 6 AS third) AS B,
    STRUCT(7 AS first, 8 AS second, 9 AS third) AS C,
    STRUCT(1 AS first, 2 AS second, 3 AS third) AS D
  ) AS results
)
SELECT id, ( 
    SELECT AS STRUCT 
      SUM(first) AS sum_first, 
      SUM(second) AS sum_second, 
      SUM(third) AS sum_third 
    FROM UNNEST([a]||[b]||[c]||[d])
  ).*
FROM `project.dataset.table`,
UNNEST([results])
```

with output

```
Row id  sum_first   sum_second  sum_third    
1   1   13          17          21
```

Answer (score 0):

I adapted [Mikhail's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62687812/7391782) in order to support grouping on the values of the lowest-level fields:

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION Nested_AGGREGATE(entries ANY TYPE, field_name STRING) AS ((
  SELECT ARRAY(
    SELECT AS STRUCT TRIM(SPLIT(kv, ':')[OFFSET(1)], '"') AS value, COUNT(SPLIT(kv, ':')[OFFSET(1)]) AS count
    FROM UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(TO_JSON_STRING(entries), r'":{(.*?)}')) entry,
    UNNEST(SPLIT(entry)) kv
    WHERE TRIM(SPLIT(kv, ':')[OFFSET(0)], '"') = field_name
    GROUP BY TRIM(SPLIT(kv, ':')[OFFSET(1)], '"')
 )
));
SELECT id, 
  Nested_AGGREGATE(results, 'first') AS first_agg,
  Nested_AGGREGATE(results, 'second') AS second_agg,
  Nested_AGGREGATE(results, 'third') AS third_agg,
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

Output for `` WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (SELECT 1 AS id, STRUCT( STRUCT(1 AS first, 2 AS second, 3 AS third) AS A, STRUCT(4 AS first, 5 AS second, 6 AS third) AS B, STRUCT(7 AS first, 8 AS second, 9 AS third) AS C, STRUCT(1 AS first, 2 AS second, 3 AS third) AS D) AS results ) ``:

```
Row  id  first_agg.value  first_agg.count  second_agg.value  second_agg.count  third_agg.value  third_agg.count     
1    1   1                2                2                 2                 3                2                                      
         4                1                5                 1                 6                1
         7                1                8                 1                 9                1
```

Comment: you might wanted to accept my respective answer as looks like it really helped!